# how to add tap to click to 2-in-1 touchscreen-identified as wacom usb

Tags: touchscreen, wacom, xorg.conf

I want to add tap to click to my touchscreen that came with the 2-in-1

computer sees it as a usb wacom device with an empty battery

inside my /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d I found these two 40-libinput.conf  70-wacom.conf

70-wacom.conf shows this

```
# Some of the below input classes appear 3x times, once for each of
# "tablet", "touchscreen", and "touchpad" to ensure that the Wacom
# driver is not accidentally bound to other types of hardware that
# Wacom has made which are not handled by the wacom driver (e.g the
# Wacom Bluetooth Keyboard)
#
# https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/bugs/294/

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Wacom USB tablet class"
        MatchUSBID "056a:*"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        MatchIsTablet "true"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Wacom USB touchscreen class"
        MatchUSBID "056a:*"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "true"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Wacom USB touchpad class"
        MatchUSBID "056a:*"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        MatchIsTouchpad "true"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Wacom tablet class"
    MatchProduct "Wacom|WACOM|PTK-540WL|ISD-V4"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    MatchIsTablet "true"
    Driver "wacom"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Wacom touchscreen class"
    MatchProduct "Wacom|WACOM|PTK-540WL|ISD-V4"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    MatchIsTouchscreen "true"
    Driver "wacom"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Wacom touchpad class"
    MatchProduct "Wacom|WACOM|PTK-540WL|ISD-V4"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    MatchIsTouchpad "true"
    Driver "wacom"
EndSection

# Serial Wacom devices should always be one of tablet, touchscreen, or
# touchpad so we can safely get away with just one match section in
# these cases
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Wacom PnP device class"
        MatchPnPID "WACf*|WCOM*|WACM*|FUJ02e5|FUJ02e7|FUJ02e9"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Wacom serial class"
    MatchProduct "Serial Wacom Tablet"
    Driver "wacom"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Wacom serial class identifiers"
        MatchProduct "WACf|FUJ02e5|FUJ02e7|FUJ02e9"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection

# Hanwang tablets
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Hanwang class"
    MatchProduct "Hanwang"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "wacom"
EndSection

# Waltop tablets
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Waltop class"
    MatchProduct "WALTOP"
    MatchIsTablet "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "wacom"
EndSection

# N-Trig Duosense Electromagnetic Digitizer
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Wacom N-Trig class"
    MatchProduct "HID 1b96:0001|N-Trig Pen|N-Trig DuoSense"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "wacom"
    Option "Button2" "3"
EndSection

# Dell Canvas 27 (touch part is an Advanced Silicon, pen part a Wacom)
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Dell Canvas 27 Touch"
        MatchUSBID "2575:0204"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "true"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection

# Surface Go
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "SurfaceGo Touch"
        MatchProduct "ELAN9038:00 04F3:261A"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection

# Nuvision Solo 10 Draw (Supports Surface Pens)
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Nuvision Solo 10 Draw"
        MatchProduct "04F3200A:00 04F3:22F7"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "wacom"
EndSection
```

40-libinput.conf shows this

```
# Match on all types of devices but joysticks
#
# If you want to configure your devices, do not copy this file.
# Instead, use a config snippet that contains something like this:
#
# Section "InputClass"
#   Identifier "something or other"
#   MatchDriver "libinput"
#
#   MatchIsTouchpad "on"
#   ... other Match directives ...
#   Option "someoption" "value"
# EndSection
#
# This applies the option any libinput device also matched by the other
# directives. See the xorg.conf(5) man page for more info on
# matching devices.

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput keyboard catchall"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput tablet catchall"
        MatchIsTablet "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: kununtu 22.04 jammy